# My Quick Sort implementation in Java is sorting only part of the array. Not sure why it's doing this

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I wrote some code to learn the quicksort algorithm in java. I believe this should work the way I have it but I'm something here as the entire array does not get sorted correctly. I've reviewed this several times but have not gotten any luck. Thank you in advance for any insight you can provide on my code.

Below wacky values are returned from the code.

> [9, 105, 45, 1, 19, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 1852, 1852, 180]

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger?

Comment: There are `13` elements in your array. Maybe use `Array.length` to avoid counting problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see three issues-

1. The length of array is 13, but you are passing 11 as end index (should be 12)
2. More importantly, there's problem with swap at the end of partition function. It should be arr[i+1] = rval, instead of arr[i] = rval.
3. You don't need a while loop, nor do you need to increment and decrease start and end indices.

Corrected code is-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = { 9, 105, 45, 1, 19, 1852, 3, 0, 66, 9, 2,125, 180 };
    quickSort(arr, 0, 12);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}

public static void quickSort(int [] arr, int start, int end){
    if(start < end){
        int q = partition(arr, start, end);
        quickSort(arr, start, q-1);
        quickSort(arr, q+1, end);
    }
}

public static int partition(int [] arr, int p, int r){
    int x = arr[r];
    int i = p - 1;
    for(int j = p; j <= r-1; j++){
        if(arr[j] <= x){
            i++;
            int ival = arr[i];
            int jval = arr[j];
            arr[i] = jval;
            arr[j] = ival;

        }
    }
    int rval = arr[r];
    int i1val = arr[i + 1];
    arr[r] = i1val;
    arr[i+1] = rval;
    return i + 1;
}
```

Edit : Turns out all this was pointed out in other answers while I was writing this one. I guess there's no harm leaving the answer here though.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest problem in your code is located at the bottom of the `partition` method:

```
int rval = arr[r];
int i1val = arr[i + 1];
arr[r] = i1val;
arr[i] = rval; // <-- here
```

You're setting `i1val` to `arr[i + 1]`, but then you set `arr[i]` to `rval` instead of setting `arr[i + 1]` to `rval`.

Fixing this, along with the array length problem mentioned in [Boris the Spider's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153630/my-quick-sort-implementation-in-java-is-sorting-only-part-of-the-array-not-sure/39153884#comment65651067_39153630), should fix your code.

Comment: to add onto this, the code could probably be made a lot cleaner by having a look at the pseudocode on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort). There are a lot of -1's and +1's everywhere currently in an attempt to make things work, but those easily cause these off-by-one errors.

Comment: @DennisSoemers agreed, as well as using descriptive variable names and only using one temporary variable when swapping.

Answer (score 0):

The `quicksort` method should have an `if` instead of a `while`. I did not check the rest of the code yet, but that part is definitely wrong. The recursive calls should already make sure you keep going till it's sorted, there is no need for an additional loop around that.

Comment: sorry that was a typo. I changed it

Comment: Yea the whole thing was the wrong code and output. I just updated it and also took some recomendations. It's returning the following now: `[9, 105, 45, 1, 19, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 1852, 1852, 180]`